# Android G2 touchscreen is left-right reversed

Tags: htc-desire-z, touchscreen

The touch screen on my Android G2 is suddenly reversed. I touch an icon on one side of the screen and an icon on the opposite side is selected. I slide to pick up the phone and instead the sound is turned off.

I scoured the web for an answer but all I found was this question.

http://community.htc.com/na/htc-forums/android/f/99/p/8610/37534.aspx#37534

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That's crazy. Are you using any sort of home screen replacement?

Comment: I tried to do a factory reset to my G2 to fix the exact same problem. I was at one of those cell phone repair shops, and the employee there told me a factory reset would fix the issue. It didn't. So, he took the phone to the back of the store for a few minutes, I guess he took it apart and gave it a look over, and came out saying that it must be a problem a hardware problem, and he couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

A friend had this issue with his new HTC Desire Z. It had this issue right out of the box. The only solution he found was resetting the device to the factory settings. If you try that, make sure you have a backup of your data! The app *MyBackup Pro* (non free) has always worked for me....